# Handling variable number of fields in ASP.NET WebForms Page

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I wanted to gather some methods on how to add a variable number of fields to my form (with Add New and Remove buttons).  I know that ASP.NET MVC has easy methods, but I'm unable to find any easy methods for WebForms.

Here's what I've used so far:

- Adding a new UserControl to a PlaceHolder on PostBack (I've had to fiddle with ViewState to make this work correctly, huge pain)
- Adding a new row to a grid and having a template field in a grid (works decently but kind of awkward)
- Actually having several fields on the form by default and hiding/showing them dynamically (fairly easy but you have a set number of fields.)

Any other methods?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add them with Javascript and on postback get their value with

```
Request.Params["ControlId_1"]
```

You just need a convention on the ControlId naming.

Comment: Is there a way to add a user control instead of simply an input?

Comment: As you said, you can add a UserControl to a Placeholder, but you have to reconstruct them all on every postback to avoid Viewstate issues. I figured you are looking for an alternative solution.